# One Regex that matches everything between two words with one condition

Tags: javascript

I need to match (word)……everything between…… (first:(or))

## Example

**Input**
You can either drive to the airport or get a taxi but don't walk or bike there.

**Match**
You can `either` drive to the airport `or` get a taxi but don't walk or bike there.

**Output**
`either` drive to the airport `or`

## What I tried

`(either\s).*(\sor)`
But it wouldn't get the first or…

```js
a = "You can either drive to the airport or get a taxi but don't walk or bike there."
b = /(either\s).*(\sor)/g.exec(a)
console.log(b[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

`/(either\s).+?(\sor)/g`

```js
a = "You can either drive to the airport or get a taxi but don't walk or bike there."
b = /(either\s).+?(\sor)/g.exec(a)
console.log(b[0])
```